TikZ - draw tank shaped figure. Problems with \fill command
I want to draw this tank. The problem is that I want a grey ellipse at the top.
As if this is a tank where we can see through the tank where the water is. But I want the section over the water level to be more gray-ish to illustrate that there is a top section there. Now the blue color dominate over the top cylinder so to say.
Hope this wasnt to badly worded. I appreciate any feedback.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{100}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HW}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\HC}{6}
% water
\fill[blue!40] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180,smooth] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},0)
-- 
plot[variable=\x,domain=180:360,smooth] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HW)
-- cycle;
\draw[gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HW);
%top
\fill[gray!40] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180,smooth] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},6)
-- 
plot[variable=\x,domain=180:360,smooth] ({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HW)
-- cycle;
\draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HW);
% "invisible" lined
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=180:360,smooth]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},0);
% visible cylinder lines
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180,smooth]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},0) 
-- 
plot[variable=\x,domain=180:360,smooth]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HC) -- cycle;
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180,smooth]
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},\HC); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome. // Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

It may be necessary or reasonable in your specific case to create the ellipses via the plot command, but you could also just use ellipse or arc to make things a bit simpler. As for the fill color: If you want the blue ellipse on the top to have a different color, you could just redraw it using some other tint, such as black!50!blue!40 (meaning: mix black and blue 50% and then mix the result 40% with white).

Okey, thank you for the feedback. I got it to work now.
the plot command was a bit easier for tweaking the figure the way I wanted
